# The SessionState presents a different behavior when the session mode changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I found a problem that occurs when the session mode is "SQLServer". 
I've isolated the problem in the following example:

In a web application using .Net 3.5 I have the following items:

1) two classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> bars;

    public Foo(List<Bar> bars)
    {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

    public List<Bar> Bars
    {
        get { return bars ?? (bars = new List<Bar>()); }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Bar
{
    public int PropertyBar { get; set; }
}
```

2) a user control

```
public partial class UserControl : UserControl
{
    public List<Bar> Bars
    {
        get { return Session["Bars"] as List<Bar>; }
        set { Session["Bars"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Bars.Add(new Bar { PropertyBar = Bars.Last().PropertyBar+1});
        }
    }
}
```

3) an aspx page with the user control and a button:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public List<Bar> Bars
    {
        get
        {
            var foo = Session["Foo"] as Foo;
            if (foo != null)
            {
                return foo.Bars;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var foo = new Foo(new List<Bar>{new Bar{PropertyBar = 1}, new Bar{PropertyBar = 2}});
            Session["Foo"] = foo;
            userControl.Bars = foo.Bars;
        }
        else
        {
            Bars.Add(new Bar { PropertyBar = 5 });
        }
    }

    protected void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text = string.Format("Default.aspx has {0} bars ({1}); UserControl has {2} bars ({3})",
            Bars.Count, Bars.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, i) => s + i.PropertyBar + ",").TrimEnd(','),
            userControl.Bars.Count, userControl.Bars.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, i) => s + i.PropertyBar + ",").TrimEnd(','));
    }
}
```

Using this:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="20" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
 sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SessionDB;User Id=XXX;Password=YYY;"     />
```

I press the button and the result is:

```
 Default.aspx has 5 bars (1,2,3,4,5); UserControl has 4 bars (1,2,3,4)
```

But if I use this:

```
<!--<sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="20" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
 sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SessionDB;User Id=XXX;Password=YYY;" /> -->
```

I press the button and the result is:

```
Default.aspx has 5 bars (1,2,3,4,5); UserControl has 5 bars (1,2,3,4,5)
```

My questions are:

1) Why this behavior occurs only when the mode of the session is "SqlServer"?

2) How should I use the session in this example correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to question 2 is this:

```
public interface IHasBars
{
    List<Bar> Bars { get; }
}

public partial class _Default : Page, IHasBars
{
    //...
}

public partial class UserControl : UserControl
{
    private List<Bar> bars; 
    private List<Bar> Bars
    {
        get 
        {
            if (bars==null)
            {
                var hasBars = Page as IHasBars;
                if (hasBars != null)
                {
                    return bars = hasBars.Bars;
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException("You can only use this userControl inside a IHasBars");
            }
            return bars;
        }
    }

    //...
```

In this way always the same list is used. But I still do not understand why the otherwise not.